# Why does 'while' cause the program to run longer in Python

Tags: python, python-3.6

I wrote a program to find out the primes in a list of numbers, just so practice formatting and all. Here is my code:

```
from math import *
#Defining range to be checked
a = range(1,10)
#Opening empty list
b = []
#Wilsons method for primes
for n in a:
    if ((factorial(n-1))+1)%n == 0:
        b.append(n)
```

This code runs without issue and fairly fast, at least at this stage of use. However, when I include a while statement(see below), it is substantially slower.

```
from math import *
#Defining range to be checked
a = range(1,10)
#Opening empty list
b = []
#Wilson't method for primes
for n in a:
    while n>1:
        if ((factorial(n-1))+1)%n == 0:
            b.append(n)
```

Could anyone explain why that would be the case?

n.b: I know there are more efficient method to find primes. I am just practicing formatting and all, although I don't mind improving my code.

edit: mistaken addition of less than symbol rather than the appropriate greater than symbol. Corrected.

Comment: The second code should be much faster, as `n` starts at `1` and therefore never satisfies `n<1` and never computes `factorial(...`. And then it should raise an `IndexError` for `b[1]`, because it never added anything to `b`.

Comment: `while n<1:` is `False` because `a` ranges from 1 to 10. The code can't work! Are you sure? and if it was True it would be an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't think there is need for while loop at all

Comment: If you say `when I include a while statement(see below), it is substantially slower.` how did you time it? Without a reproducible timing setup you can't know if it's substantially slower or if you just had a I/O hickup and the `open` or `write` was postponed a bit.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake in asking the question here. I did, indeed keep n>1.

Comment: As you do not change (reduce) the value of `n` in your while loop the loop condition will always be satisfied, resulting in an infinite loop

Comment: @MSeifert That would only be true in the first loop iteration

Comment: @JayParikh: I included while because otherwise 1 satisfies the conditions, whereas 1 is not a prime. I could have just begun the range from 2 but didn't want to.

Comment: longer how? like _forever_ ? cos you got an infinite loop here now. n never changes within the loop.

Comment: @MSeifert: I don't know(yet!) how to find the runtime of a script. Will learn that. This is my first foray into programming!

Comment: @M.T you're right, I removed that comment.

Comment: just do `a = range(2,10)` and you skip 1. Period.

Comment: @HarshA.Joshi then you can use if condition , if n==1: continue would work.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: So, what do I do if my intention is for the program to disregard 1. another for statement?

for n in a:
    for n>1:
        if ((factorial(n-1))+1)%n == 0:
            b.append(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by several people your code will result in an infinite loop as the value of `n` does not change **within** your `while`-loop.

You are probably not looking for a `while` loop in the first place. It should be sufficient to use the `for` loop without the first iteration (n = 1). If you insist on including n=1, using an `if` statement is a possible workaround:

```
a=range(1,10)
b=[]
for n in a:
    if n>1:
        if ((factorial(n-1))+1)%n == 0:
            b.append(n)
```